# How can I launch a browser via TestComplete script?

Tags: jscript, testcomplete

I just installed TestComplete 9, and for some reason that I can't figure out, my JScript script will not launch my browser. I have added the full browser path to TestedApps. I am new to TC, but I assume that since the script is a part of the project, it should inherit the TestedApps?

Tried this with IE, Chrome, and Firefox.

Any insight would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this JScript code:

```
Browsers.Item(btIExplorer).Run("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: Actually it seems that scripts in general are not executing for me (but keyword tests are). When I run a script, it completes successfully almost immediately, but does not actually execute the script.

Comment: How are you starting the script? Try the following way: right-click in any line within your function and choose Run the current routine from the context menu.